# Getting Date from database in a string

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to get date from my database into a string and comparing it with the today's date to perform some operation. 
 What I did as a solution but still the label isn't displaying the messages.

```
                      if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
    {
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        //Save files to disk
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files/" + FileName));
        string FilePath = "Files/" + FileName;
        //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DAL obj = new DAL();
        using (SqlConnection conn = obj.openCon())
        {
            String sql = "Select DueDate from tbl_AssignmentUpload1 where AssignmentTitle like '" + AssignmentTitle + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DateTime duedate = new DateTime() ;


            if (dr != null && dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    duedate = dr.GetDateTime(0);
                }
                dr.Close();

                // now check if today greater than due date and update
                if (duedate != null && today.Date > duedate)
                {
                    sql = "Insert into tbl_AssignmentSubmit( Name ,AridNumber, Shift , Degree , Course , FileName ,FilePath ) values ('" + txt_Name.Text + "' , '" + txt_AridNumber.Text + "', '" + shift + "', '" + Degree + "', '" + Course + "','" + FileName + "','" + FilePath + "')";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    lbl_uploaded.Text = "Assignment can not be Submitted.You crossed the due date.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be useful to see what the error is :)

Comment: Did you realize `date` variable doesn't holds the date actually?

Comment: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

Comment: I want to know how to retrieve date from database and use it further.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes I did. I don't know how to deal with that.

Comment: Tip: Don't use formatted sql queries, might be attack by sql injection and if you still using it then use string.Format() to format sql query make more easy to ready query and write also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get `DueDate`  from `tbl_AssignmentUpload1`  .
For example :

```
string strSQL = "Select DueDate from tbl_AssignmentUpload1 where AssignmentTitle like          @AssignmentTitle ";
(SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, cnn)) // Cnn is your sql connection
{ 
  myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AssignmentTitle", AssignmentTitle );
  using (SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (reader.Read())
    {
     DateTime today1 = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DueDate "].ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

After this you can do your insert statement

Comment: Why are you using myCommand.AddWithValue("@userID",user) here?

Comment: The last line is giving system Invalid cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Ok updated with the fix for duedate.

```
                using (SqlConnection conn = SQL.GeSQLConnection())
                {
                    String sql = "Select DueDate from tbl_AssignmentUpload1 where AssignmentTitle like '" + AssignmentTitle + "'";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DateTime duedate = new DateTime();
                    if (dr != null && dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            duedate = dr.GetDateTime(0);
                        }
                        dr.Close();

                        // now check if today greater than due date and update
                       if(duedate != null && DateTime.Today > duedate)
                       {
                        sql = "Insert into tbl_AssignmentSubmit( Name ,AridNumber, Shift , Degree , Course , FileName ,FilePath ) values ('" + txt_Name.Text + "' , '" + txt_AridNumber.Text + "', '" + shift +"', '" + Degree + "', '" + Course + "','" + FileName + "','" + FilePath + "')";
                        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        lbl_uploaded.Text = "Assignment can not be Submitted.You crossed the due date.";
                      }
                    }
                    else
                      {
                        lbl_uploaded.Text = "No Due date was selected for the given assesment title";
                      }
                }
```

Comment: The program is giving an error on this line.
Saying It cannot convert null to dateTime format.                  DateTime duedate = null;

Comment: @user2444546 just make it DateTime duedate = new DateTime(); see the updated code.

Comment: The code is running fine without any errors, but the label doesn't display the text. Either Submitted or not.
Here is the code, see if I am doing some mistake.

Comment: Do you mean there is no result for the select query? see the updated code please.

Comment: Yes. Although the database contains value.

Comment: 1. check your query directly with the database. 2.Check id DueDate is of type DateTime in database. 3. try to hard code the AssignmentTitle and see if you get the result.

Comment: I checked all three of them. Everything seems to be working just fine. I don't know how to solve this :(

Comment: plz use the debug mode to see where is the problem. Or in case of any exception plz be clear on the issue

Comment: Can you suggest me of some other way to do the same task?